# Rename and add tag synonym for [tag:windows-subsystem-linux] like the remaining stackexchange sites

Tags: feature-request, retag-request

As the [global maximum tag length has been increased to 35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/230282), now the tag [windows-subsystem-linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-linux) should be renamed to [windows-subsystem-for-linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux) (or similar) and act as a synonym to the latter. [wsl](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wsl) should also be a synonym for it.

**Other SE sites have already done the change**

- Superuser: [Should WSL be a synonym for Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12738/241386)
- Unix: [The tag 'windows-subsystem-for-linux' is too long; the maximum length is 25 characters](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4226/44425)
- Stack Overflow: [tag windows-subsystem-for-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-subsystem-for-linux/synonyms)
- Ask Ubuntu: [Add tag synonym for [tag:wsl]](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18029/253474)

The same thing should also be done on this site

There's also the tag [linux-subsystem](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/linux-subsystem) but I don't know what it's for because there's no wiki page for it

Comment: more than a year and still almost no one reads this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem to rename the tag. It's more logic to rename it to the real name.

It's done.